# How to extract text before several specified alphanumeric whole words from string in plsql

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, regexp-substr

How to remove all characters after specific alphanumeric value from string
for example "covid19 1st case" should be "covid19" if we remove string after 1st;
in case of "covid19 2d case" it should be "covid19" if we remove string after 2d
I am trying below query

```
select regexp_substr('covid19 1st case','[^1st]*') from dual;
```

but its giving covid as output any lead.
if we have predefine alphanumeric values can we do it in single expression
like we can remove all string after 1st and 2d.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `select regexp_replace('covid19 1st case','(1st|2d).*', '') from dual;`?

Comment: Or, `select regexp_substr('covid19 1st case','^(.*?)\s*(1st|2d)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) from dual;`?

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor Stribiżew 
I think there is one thing I have missed if string is like "covid19 1std 1st case" then it should remove string after 1st not after  1std. how to remove exact match string only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sql
select regexp_substr('covid19 1st case','^(.*?)\s+(1st|2d)($|\W)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) from dual;
select regexp_substr('covid19 1st case','^(.*?)\s*(^|\W)(1st|2d)($|\W)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) from dual;
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/uAs0kl/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/uAs0kl/2).

The `(^|\W)` and `($|\W)` are used instad of word boundaries that are not supported by Oracle SQL regex engine.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces (`\s+` matches one or more)
- `(^|\W)` - Group 2: start of string or a non-word char
- `(1st|2d)` - Group 3: either `1st` or `2d`
- `($|\W)` - Group 4: end of string or a non-word char.

Another variation is using `REGEXP_REPLACE` (you just need to match the rest of the string):

```sql
select regexp_replace('covid19 1st case','^(.*?)\s*(\W|^)(1st|2d)(\W|$).*', '\1') from dual;
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uAs0kl/3), `\1` refers to the Group 1 value.